# Error - 11750 ## TwiML response body too large In your response to Twilio's request, the response body is larger than 64 kB

Tags: google-cloud-platform, twilio, bucket

I'm trying to access an audio file which is stored in a GCP bucket from a TwiML template which has the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
   <Play>https://storage.cloud.google.com/.../.../welcome.wav</Play>
</Response>
```

When I am logged into my GCP account and I try to access this file from the browser, I have no issues. But, when Twilio tries to access it, the following error occurs:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11750

Also, when I execute the following from the command line:

```
curl -v https://storage.cloud.google.com/.../.../welcome_en.wav
```

I get the following HTTP response:

```
HTTP/2 302 
content-type: application/binary
```

This doesn't seem to be a permissions issue since when I try to access the same file without GCP authentication, I get a HTTP 403 (Forbidden) error.

How do I successfully access this file, which is in a GCP bucket, from Twilio?

Comment: No, I have no idea about Twilio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility, is that your content type is wrong. According to this page on [Supported Audio File Types](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play#supported-audio-file-types), Twilio Play is compatible with:

```
MIME type   Description
audio/mpeg  mpeg layer 3 audio
audio/wav   wav format audio
audio/wave  wav format audio
audio/x-wav wav format audio
audio/aiff  audio interchange file format
audio/x-aifc    audio interchange file format
audio/x-aiff    audio interchange file format
audio/x-gsm GSM audio format
audio/gsm   GSM audio format
audio/ulaw  μ-law audio format
```

"application/binary" isn't on the list. I play audio files from blob storage and specify the content type for the blob. Are you able to specify a content type for the blob in the GCP bucket?

You should also check the Twilio Console to find the cause of the "response body too large". It could be that the GPC is returning a login page or an unauthorized error and that is making the Twiml too large for Twilio to process. The Twilio Console should have an error in the error log or open the call that caused the error and view the Twiml.

Comment: Appreciate your response. In the GCP bucket, the file is designated as "audio/wav" using metadata but I still receive the same error.

Comment: Back to the original error 11750, can you confirm that your "GPC" is actually returning an audio file and not something else like a login page or something with HTML. Having an audio file larger than 64k is not a problem. The Twilio Console should show the actual Twiml and possibly the body of the response.

Comment: Just to clarify, I have a Python app working with Twilio so in the first encounter, the app returns a TwiML template to Twilio in the response which has the structure: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Response> <Play>storage.cloud.google.com/.../.../welcome.wav</Play> </Response>. Then, when Twilio requests this file from GCP using a redirect (i.e. HTTP 302), the response is empty. I can confirm that the file is present in the bucket since I am able to play it from my browser.

Comment: Digging deeper, the response is empty because the second call is a GET call from Twilio, not a POST. This GET call in turn calls https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin, which in turn calls https://accounts.google.com/InteractiveLogin. It seems there are several redirects to get the file but nothing is finally returned.

Comment: This means it is a problem with GPC - not so much with Twilio. My guess is the browser handles those redirects, headers, and stored cookies better than a straight get request. Postman or a REST client would probably have the same issues. FYI...I play audio from blobs all the time but they are hosted in Azure. I have not tried to play an audio file from a shared folder like OneDrive or DropBox. If you need a public place to host the audio use a Twilio Serverless Static Asset.

Comment: Agree, I think the issue is the content-type since GCP is not sending back any headers to Twilio informing it that the file type is "audio/wav". Any idea how I can force GCP to send a content-type header? As mentioned earlier, in the GCP bucket, the "Type" is already defined as "audio/wav".

Comment: @Foobar, I am not familiar with GCP. It could also be that a cached version of the file is being served that has the wrong content-type. Try uploading a new file with a new name and the correct content-type.

Comment: More on this. I don't think this is a content type issue anymore since even with curl, when I try to get the file from the GCP bucket, 0 bytes are returned. Seems like a permissions issue now but the response from GCP is an HTTP 302, which points to a redirect. For files that are going to be used by the Python app and aren't user related, should I be using Twilio Serverless Static Asset instead of GCP?

Comment: Twilio Serverless Static Assets will have very little (or no) monthly cost. I don't know GCP enough to know why it is using a redirect and not offering a direct link that opens the blob without a redirect.

Comment: Figured this out. It was a permissions issue after all. Made the bucket publicly accessible and that did the trick. Thanks for all your help.